# Can't run uwsgi as root, "bind(): Permission denied"

Tags: linux, nginx, uwsgi

I try to configure uWsgi, Django ,Nginx with this document:
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Finish config the `uwsgi.ini` file, create a soft link at `/etc/uwsgi/vassals`.

Failed at the last step :**Make uWSGI startup when the system boots**.

When run this command:

`sudo /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data`

I got this error:

```
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
your processes number limit is 3813
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 227]
Tue May 27 05:29:26 2014 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance uwsgi.ini (pid: 1391)
Tue May 27 05:29:29 2014 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance uwsgi.ini
```

If I run this command without `sudo`, everything is OK.

I've add user "kk" into group "www-data", and here is the `uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /home/kk/XXXXXXX
module          = wsgi
home            = /home/kk/XXXXXXX

master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /home/kk/XXXXXXX/mysite.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
```

I guess maybe I made mistake on file permission. Does anybody have good idea?Thank you.

---

Update:

The official document is correct, I follow the steps to deploy the project in another new VPS, no error occurred.

Comment: if the emperor runs as www-data all of its vassals will run as www-data. For this reason /home/kk/XXXXXX must be writable by www-data.

Comment: @roberto kk is a member of group of www-data, the project folder's mod is 775. It's strange that I can run this command as kk but failed as root.

Comment: double check if there is already a socket file not owned by www-data

Comment: @roberto No, before I run the command, there's no socket file in project folder.

Comment: @Hunger I ran into the same error ? DO you have a solution for this?

Comment: @MevinBabu I still can't find the reason, I use `su kk -c "XXXXX"` instead.

Comment: @Hunger Were you able to run uwsgi at boot ?

Answer (score 20):

I don't know why the permissions don't work, but I ran into the same problem.

One quick way to fix this is to move the sockets to /tmp though! (Which is a fairly reasonable place to keep sockets anyway...)

so just update the uwsgi config with:

```
socket          = /tmp/mysite.sock
```

and the nginx-config with:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/mysite.sock;
}
```

and it'll start working!

Comment: After much frustration with the above problem as well, went with this solution and now in business. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you.  I used the socket change to fix my first flask app and it started working.

Answer (score 18):

I was having this problem. Running without setting the group and user ids solved the problem. I'll probably revisit this when I have more time to fix file permissions for the directory, but it works for the moment

`/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals`

**EDIT** 
I've had time to revisit this answer and I'd have to say that this is *not* good practice when running uwsgi in production.

The problem with the tutorial as written is that it assumes that `www-data` is a user and that the `www-data` user and group has access to all the files it needs on your server; in particular the socket file. Replace the appropriate arguments with your user and group and and you'll be good to go (and won't leave a gaping security hole on your server).

So, the correct command (if I was user `ovangle` in group `ovangle` would be):

`/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid ovangle --gid ovangle`

It would be better to create a user which has the specific permissions it needs to run the server successfully, but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 4):

You did the permissions backwards.

uwsgi is running as www-data.

Your socket is in kk's home directly which is presumably owned by the kk user and the kk group.

You made it so that kk can access everything that www-data owns, not so www-data can access what kk owns.

You want to add the www-data to kk's group.  This way www-data can reach the socket in kk's home.

```
usermod www-data -aG kk
```

Confirm with `groups www-data` and you should get back `www-data : www-data kk` showing that www-data is now in kk's primary group.

Now, provided kk's home folder permissions have at least '6' for the group permission www-data can read and write to the socket as necessary.  E.g. `chmod 660 /home/kk/XXXXXXX/mysite.sock`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got the socket to start securely.  Are you running in a virtualenv?  I got the same error message when I was sourced to the virtualenv with my app, since there's no sudo in the env.  I had to `deactivate` the virtualenv then to install uwsgi globally.  After installing uWSGI I needed to download the python3 plugin with `sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python3`, and add "plugins = python3" to my uWSGI ini file.  After all of that I was able to start uWSGI with sudo/root eq. `sudo uwsgi --ini mysite.ini`.

As for security it's recommended to add these lines to the ini file:

```
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
chmod-socket = 644

# Plus here's the plugin I mentioned
plugins = python3
```

For these to be honored www-data has to own the parent directory where the mysite.sock file will be created, and the `uwsgi` command needs to be started with sudo.  If either of those options are off then the socket gets created as the user who ran the `uwsgi` command.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue you asking about is that uwsgi is trying to create a unix socket file to interact with a webserver via fastCGI protocol in directory you configured **/home/kk/XXXXXXX/**
You should set write permissions for the user you run uwsgi from to the directory **/home/kk/XXXXXXX/**

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the exact same problem, after solving it by running with users and groups which have enough permission for the socket file, I realized this probably is a bug.

It's very confusing if you can actually run it in current user with `uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data` while once `sudo` is added you get `bind(): Permission denied` error.

The only explanation for this would be when you run it without `sudo`, somehow `--uid www-data --gid www-data` part **DOES NOT** work and you're actually running it with current user which have enough permision; and once `sudo` is added, `--uid www-data --gid www-data` part magically works again, which ends up with `www-data` not having enough permision to bind the socket file.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error.  It turned that my folder had the wrong owner and group.  Files inside were correct so I didn't catch it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of resurrecting an old question, but I ran into this problem.

I found the solution. I had previously run uwsgi to test something as root. Later on I tried running it as www-data. Eventually I figured out that the stats server makes a socket file in `/tmp/name.stats.sock` this was owned by root and therefore would crash uwsgi. I just removed that and it works now!

I hope this helps anyone stumbling around with this.

Answer (score 0):

My error was that I expected that if I add the site user (`USER`) to the `uwsgi` group, it'll be able to write to `/run/uwsgi`. But it turns out supplementary groups are ignored in this case. So I ended up having the socket at `/run/nginx-PRJ/socket` (`socket = /run/nginx-PRJ/socket`), adding `nginx` to the site user's group (`GROUP`), and `chmod-socket = 660`. This way `nginx` is automatically able to access the socket if SELinux is in effect:

```
# grep httpd_var_run_t /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts
/var/run/wsgi.* -s  system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/run/mod_.* system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/run/httpd.*    system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/run/nginx.*    system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/run/apache.*   system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/run/php-fpm(/.*)?  system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/run/lighttpd(/.*)? system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/lib/php/session(/.*)?  system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/lib/php/wsdlcache(/.*)?    system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/run/dirsrv/admin-serv.*    system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/opt/rh/rh-nginx18/run/nginx(/.*)?  system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/www/openshift/broker/httpd/run(/.*)?   system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/www/openshift/console/httpd/run(/.*)?  system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/opt/dirsrv/var/run/dirsrv/dsgw/cookies(/.*)?   system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/run/thttpd\.pid    --  system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/run/gcache_port    -s  system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0
/var/run/cherokee\.pid  --  system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0

# yum install setools-console

# sesearch -A -C -s httpd_t -c sock_file -p write | grep httpd_var_run_t
   allow httpd_t httpd_var_run_t : sock_file { ioctl read write create getattr setattr lock append unlink link rename open } ;

# man sesearch
       -A, --allow
              Search for allow rules.
       -C, --show_cond
              Print  the  conditional  expression and state for all conditional rules found.  This
              option has no effect on unconditional rules.
       -s NAME, --source=NAME
              Find rules with type/attribute NAME as their source.
       -p P1[,P2,...] --perm=P1[,P2...]
              Find rules with at least one of the specified permissions.  Multiple permissions may
              be  specified  as a comma separated list; it is recommended that this list be quoted
              for shells that interpret comma as a special character.
```

To make sure the dir always exists I made use of `systemd-tmpfiles`:

`/etc/tmpfiles.d/PRJ.conf`:

```
d /run/nginx-PRJ 0750 USER GROUP
```

```
# systemd-tmpfiles --create PRJ.conf
```

I'm running CentOS 7, and `uwsgi-2.0.17.1-2.el7` in tyrant mode. In this case specifying `gid`, `uid` is not necessary. They are taken from the ini-file's permissions.

Answer (score -1):

If you are okay using a web port socket (like the first part of the demo) instead of unix sockets.. you could change this..

```
# uwsgi.ini
socket = :8001
```

and this..

```
# mysite_nginx.conf
upstream django {
    # server unix:///home/teewuane/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}
```

and you will avoid the permission issues.

Comment: I'm having still having this issue with even with ports