# why docker-compose fails when vanila docker succeeds (permission)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run uwsgi, and it works fine if I run with `docker run -d foo` but fails if I do `docker-compose up` with error

> bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 230]

docker-compose.yml

```
 services:
   web:
     restart: always
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: ./compose/production/web/Dockerfile
     image: foo
     volumes:
       - /app
       - /var/log
```

Dockerfile

```
....
CMD uwsgi --uid www-data --gid www-data  --emperor /app/momsite/momsite/conf/docker/etc/uwsgi/vassals
```

Comment: What is the user you are using for uwsgi? The possible answer is available https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886018/cant-run-uwsgi-as-root-bind-permission-denied

Comment: it was because of `volumes: /var/log` not sure why